# Is there perhaps a way of finding the above and below average

Tags: java

I'm creating a program to find the average of all the numbers entered by the user and storing those numbers to check whether the number entered falls below or above the average that was calculated.
My program outputs all numbers entered as below average. i have check on stack overflow for similar problems i have tried all that but my output still displays below the average only

This is what i have tried

```
public void newspaper()
    {
        System.out.println("Question 4 \n");
        int youth;
        double avg =0;
        int sum = 0;
        int numYouth = 5;

   //The loop for calculating the average
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Youth " + i + " How many was delivered?");
        youth = in.nextInt();

         sum = sum + youth;
         avg = sum / numYouth;


    }
       System.out.println("Average is: " + avg+ "\n");

        double aboveAvg = 0;

      //The loop for checking below of above average
        for (int j = 1; j <=5; j++) 
       {
           if(aboveAvg > avg)
           {                
               System.out.println("Youth " + j + " is above average");
               aboveAvg++;
           }
           else 
          {
              System.out.println("Youth " + j + " below average");

          }
       }

  }
```

Comment: have you debugged your code? I thinkyour error is in the if(aboveAvg > avg) test

Comment: As you mentioned that you need to compare the number entered to the average calculated that means you need to store them. So in the first for loop store the `youth` var. inside some data structure you feel is suitable for your problem.

Comment: The if statement yes is where the error is. when i swop the variables around it gives me only above average

Comment: Can you clarify more what does aboveAvg mean ?

Comment: @Karim the 'aboveAvg' are used to see if the numbers that was entered falls under above average or below average

Comment: That's not the case though, in your program aboveAvg starts at 0 and is only incremented after the check when students are above average. If this is intended to be a counter of the students above average it should be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution for your problem:
Note that you need to store the user inputs, calculate the average once (not inside the for loop), and finally compare the numbers stored with the average calculated before.

```
public void newspaper() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Question 4 \n");
    double avg = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int[] youths = new int[5];

    // The loop for calculating the average
    for (int i = 0; i < youths.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Youth " + (i + 1) + " How many was delivered?");
        youths[i] = in.nextInt();

        sum = sum + youths[i];
    }
    // Note that the average can be calculated once, not every iteration
    avg = sum / youths.length;
    System.out.println("Average is: " + avg + "\n");

    // The loop for checking below of above average
    for (int i = 0; i < youths.length; i++) {
        if (youths[i] > avg) {
            System.out.println("Youth " + (i + 1) + " is above average");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Youth " + (i + 1) + " below average");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So in order to store user inputs it has to be an array?

Comment: You can store user inputs in whatever data structure you like, I choose array because it's simple to understand.

Comment: i actually understand the array part more. it worked thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use array instead of variable 
see below code

```
        import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Stackoverflow {
        public void newspaper() {
            System.out.println("Question 4 \n");

            double avg = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            int numYouth = 5;
            int youth[] = new int[numYouth];
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            // The loop for calculating the average
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Youth " + i + " How many was delivered?");
                youth[i] = sc.nextInt();

                sum = sum + youth[i];
                avg = sum / numYouth;

            }
            System.out.println("Average is: " + avg + "\n");

            double aboveAvg = 0;

            // The loop for checking below of above average
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (youth[j] > avg) {
                    System.out.println("Youth " + j + " is above average");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Youth " + j + " below average");

                }
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Stackoverflow().newspaper();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're trying to 'find the average of all the numbers entered by the user, storing those numbers to check whether ***each of the numbers*** entered falls below or above the average that was calculated', below are the things you need to fix:

1. The "storing those numbers" part
2. Compare the calculated average against the stored number.

A possible solution:

- Use a list or an array to store the numbers entered by the user.
- You can use an array as long as you know the number of elements to store before starting to read the numbers.
- Read values from the list/array when you want to compare the entered value with the calculated average.

  ```
  public void newspaper()
  {
      System.out.println("Question 4 \n");
      int youth;
      double avg =0;
      int sum = 0;
      int numYouth = 5;

      // Create a list to store the entered values
      // List<Integer> enteredNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

      // Using an array of '5' elements - this 5 comes from numYouth
      int[] enteredNumbers = new int[numYouth]; // better not to 'hardcode'

      //The loop for calculating the average
      for (int i = 1; i <= numYouth; i++) 
      {
         System.out.println("Youth " + i + " How many was delivered?");
         youth = in.nextInt();

         enteredNumbers[i-1] = youth; // array is 0-indexed
         sum = sum + youth;
         avg = sum / numYouth;    
     }

     System.out.println("Average is: " + avg+ "\n");

     // an int is enough to track the number of values above the average
     int aboveAvg = 0; 

     //The loop for checking below of above average
     for (int j = 1; j <= numYouth; j++) 
     {
         // compare stored value against the average calculated above
         if(enteredNumbers[j-1] > avg) // array is 0-indexed
         {                
             System.out.println("Youth " + j + " is above average");
             aboveAvg++;
         }
         else 
         {
            System.out.println("Youth " + j + " below average");
         }
     }
     System.out.println(aboveAvg + " Youths are above average");
  ```

  }

Comment: Yes. you're correct. I've now modified the solution to use an array instead - as an arraylist seems like an overkill when we have `numYouth` value.

Comment: I understand now perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the numbers in a temporary list and use counter 'ctr' for incrementing the values of the matched case. I have used for each loop for simplicity.

```
public void newspaper() {
        System.out.println("Question 4 \n");
        int youth;
        double avg = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int numYouth = 5;

        List<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
        // The loop for calculating the average
        int ctr = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Youth " + ++ctr + " How many was delivered?");
            youth = in.nextInt();
            number.add(youth);
            sum = sum + youth;
            avg = sum / numYouth;

        }
        System.out.println("Average is: " + avg + "\n");
        ctr = 0;
        // The loop for checking below of above average
        for (int j : number) {
            if (j > avg) {
                System.out.println("Youth " + ++ctr + " is above average");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Youth " + ++ctr + " below average");

            }
        }

    }
```